# Linear equation and exponential

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have an equation I need to figure out. I apologize for my lack of knowledge and improper use of terms. My math skills are quite rusty.
Using the equation $A=P\left(1+\frac i{100}\right)^n$,

a)  If I invest $100$ dollars over the course of $95$ years at an interest rate of $7.5422$ percent. I will have saved nearly $100,000$ dollars.

$$100\left(1+\frac{7.5422}{100}\right)^{95}=100,000$$

b)  If during these $95$ years I spend a total amount of $5$ million dollars and my spending for each year is always on top of keeping exactly $7.5422$ percent carried over, my total earned would be slightly less than $5.1$ million.

The equation to calculate my total earned would be

$$5,100,000= 100\left(1+\frac{12.0865}{100}\right)^{95}$$

If $c=b-a$

$C$ is equal to the amount of money spent. $C$ is always calculated based on what $a$ is however its ratio is always different because each number is based on an exponential of a different percent.

The only way to calculate c that I have figured out is.

Using year $95$ as an example -

$$100((1.120865^{95})-(1.075422^{95}))^{95}$$

Is there a neat and tidy equation to calculate $c$? 
Is there a formula I can use to calculate $c$ for a given year and not the total amount up until and including that year? Example: how can I calculate $c$ or the total spent for only year $43$?

Comment: If anyone needs clarification on what i am asking; I'd be happy to try to explain more. I am working on a personal project and this is an important component to it. I am out of practice with my math skills and they do not go beyond the high school level. If there is anyone out here that doesn't mind sticking with me to help figure this out I would be very grateful.

Comment: It's not clear where does $12.0865%$ come from. And what does "my spending for each year is always on top of keeping exactly 7.5422 percent carried over" mean? And what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: If I spent 5,000,000 over the course or 95 years and still had a total savings of 100,000 at the end of this time period all from investing 100. 
The interest rate of the total earned is 12.0865 percent compounded annually. 

I am calling the first equation that give me the result of 100,000 "a"
and the second equation which gives me the result of 5,100,000 "b".

"C" is always going to relative to whatever the total of "a" is.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. If you invest \$100 at 12.0865% *and leave it alone* for 95 years, then it will earn \$5,100,000 for you. But if you spend the excess every year over what \$100 at 7.5422% would earn you, you won't have earned anywhere near as much money. That is because you will only be earning that 12.0865% on what you haven't spent.

Assuming you follow this spending strategy, then at the end of year $y$, the amount of money available to you for spending the next year is $$100(1.12865 - 1.075422)(1.075422)^{y-1}$$
The total amount of money you will have spent is $$100(1.12865 - 1.075422)\frac{(1.075422)^y - 1}{1.075422 - 1} \approx 70.574(1.075422)^y$$
After 95 years, this totals \$70,574, a far cry from \$5,000,000. (You will also still have your \$100,000 earned on the part you didn't spend.)